# While reading nfc tags i am getting this error?

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to make an application which is read `text/plain` type of tags. But in some times it read well and sometimes it give me this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.nfc.NdefRecord[] android.nfc.NdefMessage.getRecords()' on a
>   null object reference

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initNFC();
    NFCEnable();
}

public void NFCEnable ()
{
    NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
    NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {
        // adapter exists and is enabled.
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Enable your NFC!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void initNFC(){
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);


        if(tag != null) {
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if(ndef!=null)
        {
            readFromNFC(ndef);

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"try again!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    }
private void readFromNFC(Ndef ndef) {

    try {
        ndef.connect();


            NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getNdefMessage();
            if(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0]!=null &&!ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload().equals(""))
            {
            String message = new String(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload());

            Log.e("ok",message);
            if(message.equals("tech"))
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tech_Activation_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else   if(message.equals("event"))
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Event_Executed.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {
                Log.e("ok","blank");
            }
          }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Empty NFC TAG!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        ndef.close();
    } catch (IOException | FormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ok",e.toString());
        if(e.toString().equals("java.io.IOException"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Get your phone near to NFC!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    IntentFilter techDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter ndefDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    ndefDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    try {
        ndefDetected.addDataType("text/plain");
    } catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    IntentFilter[] nfcIntentFilter = new IntentFilter[]{techDetected,tagDetected,ndefDetected};

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    if(mNfcAdapter!= null)
        mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, nfcIntentFilter, null);

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mNfcAdapter!= null)
        mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}
```

Please let me know if there is any changes or what I am doing wrong. And also for writing data in `nfc` tags I am using free application that are `available` in play store.

Comment: if i had to guess, your problem is here : `ndefMessage.getRecords()[0]!=null` you need to check that `ndefMessage.getRecords()` isn't null or empty

Comment: thanks for response.. but some times it read well but some it crash and give this error..can tell me why this happening

Comment: still the same error..

Comment: `ndefMessage` is null it says.

Comment: but bro sometimes in same tag it read perfectly..and gives perfect output

Comment: can tell what is perfect way to read all "text/plain" type of nfc tags

Comment: hii bro i have question.. i want to specific activity when when tag discovered..in this app not foreground or background..

Comment: i have tried using manifest addes    <data android:mimeType="application/in.adsmn.nfsreader.tech" /> this line to manifest but still it not working

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TextUtils.isEmpty()`. It checks `null` and also `empty space`. It can make your code cleaner.

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0]) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload())){
    // TODO
}
```

I am not pretty sure. But you'd better to implement with `try-catch`.

Comment: actually this problem is solved..but thanks for comment and time

Comment: @VikramDulgach then, It'd be great iff you share your solution.

Comment: actually i am cheching ndef Tag is null or not and ndefMessage message in null or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if(ndef!=null)
        {
            readFromNFC(ndef);

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"try again!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```